# Display Comma (,) after every element using <h4> tag

Tags: html, css, angular

```
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs"
    ng-repeat="d in missDocs(vm.voyage) track by $index"> {{d}}</h4>
```

I Want to display comma (`,`) after every element so, do I have to make changes in css or there is some other way.

Comment: I think you can do something like `h4:after {content: ',';}` but I'd recommend researching jQuery http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is place-holder code that gets rendered as different `<h4>` tags, you can play with the [::after pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```css
h4::after {
   content: ","
}
h4:last-of-type::after{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">One</h4>
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">Two</h4>
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">Three</h4>
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">Four</h4>
```

Or just:

```css
h4:not(:last-of-type)::after {
   content: ","
}
```

```html
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">One</h4>
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">Two</h4>
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">Three</h4>
<h4 style="display: inline;" class="missing-docs">Four</h4>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use CSS to **add the comma to a psuedo element**.

```
h4::after {
  content: ",";
  display: inline-block;
}

h4:last-of-type::after{
    display: none; // removes comma after last h4 (not asked in the question)
}
```

Well you can do it with JavaScript too. But I guess the CSS solution is easy.

Comment: I was going to do this and then saw you had done exactly what I would have done :)

Comment: Yes. I guess that's the solution that comes to every one's mind. Thanks :). Have a great day.

Comment: it will display comma after the last element as well, so its better to use not(:last-child)::after

Comment: Yes. Now I have edited the answer. But that was not asked in the question(rather it said Display Comma (,) after every element using <h4> tag)  so I didn't include in the answer the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with @Kiran Dash and totally agree with that solution- I would perhaps suggest that repeating h4's are not entirely the best approach from a semantic point of view (h4's are for headings not a list of elements) - this seems more like a list and should be done with ul / li's but if you want the h4 wrapping it - then you could repeat the elements in span's (and eliminate the display: inline issue).

Then just remove the comma from the :last-of-type and you have a series of repeating spans inside the h4 - rather than a series of repeating h4's. That said - I would still do it as a list and repeat the content in li's and display them inline.... :)

```
<h4 
  <span  class="missing-docs" ng-repeat="d in missDocs(vm.voyage) track by $index"> {{d}}</span>
</h4>

//css
h4 span::after {
  content: ", ";
}

h4 span:last-of-type::after {
  content: "";
}
```

or

```
  <ul class="missing-docs">
    <li ng-repeat="d in missDocs(vm.voyage) track by $index"> {{d}} </li>
  </ul>

  //css
  .missing-docs li {
    display:inline
  }

  .missing-docs li::after {
    content: ",";
  }

  .missing-docs li:last-of-type::after {
    content: "";
  }
```

Comment: Yes the OP should definitely consider it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS `::after` selector.

```
h4::after {
  content: ",";
}
```

As well you can use jQuery `.after()` function.

```
$("h4").after(",");
```